# How to use Bazaar with Dropbox?

Tags: version-control, dropbox, bazaar

I want to write a code (in fact a latex file) with other collaborators. We wish to collaborate through Dropbox and version control our file with Bazaar.

1. *How to do it? Is there a short tutorial how to do this?*
2. *Is there a better way to collaborate on a single file in Dropbox, that is, without a version control system?*
3. *Is there a better control version system suitable for Dropbox, which is also easy to learn.*

NOTES: I use only the bare basics of version control in Bazzar. I don't know how to use any version control systems properly, unfortunately. I need some very simple mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Bazaar repository *without a working tree* on your shared dropbox folder:

```
bzr init --no-tree /path/to/subfolder/in/dropbox
```

You and your team can checkout or branch from this common repository. The good thing about not have a working tree is that nobody will work on it directly by mistake. It's cleanest if each of you checkout/branch from this repository.

If you already have an existing repository, you can push it to the dropbox folder without a working tree like this:

```
cd /your/local/working/tree
bzr push --no-tree /path/to/subfolder/in/dropbox
```

The above is a standalone repository setup. If later you want to share multiple branches with your team, it will be more optimal to use a shared repository instead. That way will save storage space and bandwidth. I think it's probably a bit advanced for you now, but if you need it in the future, you can easily migrate your existing repository to a shared repository setup like this:

```
cd /path/in/dropbox
bzr init-repo --no-trees repo
bzr branch /path/to/old/repo repo/trunk
```

Afterward you can create multiple branches side by side with `trunk` inside the repo to share within your team, and it will be efficient.

As per your second question, I think it's better to use version control rather than a single unversioned file. This is a bit of an investment, but it will surely pay off in the long term.

As per your second question, Bazaar is a very easy to use, very intuitive tool. I think it's an excellent choice for you. (Disclaimer: [I recently wrote a book on Bazaar](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BazaarBook).)

Comment: Great! I already have a repository and I pushed it to Dropbox as you demonstrated in your example two. But how should my colleagues use it? Also, some collaboration will be with a person that does not use Bazaar. Is this possible, and how?

Comment: It will be easiest if you use Bazaar in *centralized mode*: you check out from the dropbox folder using `bzr checkout /path/to/dropbox`. You can get the changes committed by others using `bzr update`. You should not let uncommitted changes hang around for a long time, as that increases the chance of conflicts. Adopt this cycle: always start with `bzr update`, do some work and `bzr commit` as soon as possible, leaving no pending changes behind. Even with inexperienced users, this should be simple and easy to follow. Bazaar Explorer can be helpful for non-technical users.